# openni_camera topics

Tags: ros, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new in ROS, therefore the question might be very simple. But I did not find any information about that. I use UBUNTU 12.4 and feurte and do something with kinect. The point is that, I want to have information about the published topics of openni_camera (any tutorial or document). I need to know what information do they have, and which of them should be for example recorded to be used later on rviz or other visualizer? What kind of TF message is been transferred?  Where can I find the general information about topics that every package publishes? I do not mean the names and type. I mean the real information they have!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34482/openni_camera-topics/) by [Antares](https://answers.ros.org/users/2375/antares/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2012-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The information you want is on the [openni_camera](http://ros.org/wiki/openni_camera) wiki page.

What to save depends on what you want to see. Those topics can use up a lot of bandwidth.

If you want the RBG camera data, save `rgb/camera_info` and `rgb/image_raw/compressed`.

If you want the depth camera, save `depth/camera_info` and `depth/image_raw`. Image compression does not work well on depth images.

Depending on what frame of reference you want to use, it probably makes sense to save the `/tf` topic, too.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0